# WebDriver:Relative Xpath is not highlighting Select box when I click evaluate button in firepath

Tags: selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, webdriver, firepath

Html select tag contains Id. I have used id in relative path and testing in firepath by clicking evaluate button.firepath returns only one matching node but select box is not highlighted. It clearly says that select box wont be handle. I tried in many ways and not helped me. Please find the html tag on below

```
<select id="myForm:operatingUnit" class="ef-combo-container" style="display:none;" name="myForm:operatingUnit">
<option value="-1">Please Select</option>
<option value="702">Industrial Casualty</option>
<option value="703">General Casualty</option>
<option value="704">Specialty Primary</option>
</select>
<input id="myForm:operatingUnit_input" class="combo-input ui-autocomplete-input" value="Please Select" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" title="Please Select"/>

Please find the relative xpath on below:
//select[@id='myForm:operatingUnit']
```

I have used various explict wait statments as well but not working out to overcome from this issue.
Please help me to overcome from this problem

Comment: Have you checked if the element is contained in an iframe? Also you can try with the following css: input[id*=myForm][id*=operatingUnit]

Comment: it is not inside the frame. size is displaying correctly. 

system.out.println(weblement.getOptions().size)

It returns size as 4

Answer (score 1):

How `Select` is suppose to display? In `HTML` code I can see the `css property` as:-

```
style="display:none;"
```

Due to this property the element isn't displayed on the webpage. Whats the issue here?

If you remove this `CSS` property the element would be displayed on the webpage and it would be highlighted using the `xpath` that you have used.

If you want to still interact with the element, you have to modify the css property of the element, below is the code to modify that:-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("myForm:operatingUnit"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, "display:unset;");
```

Once its modified the `Select` would be displayed and then you can interact with it.

Comment: its an client application. we cant made any changes in the html tag part. Is there any other way to handle in webdriver?

Comment: I've modified my answer.